# Why is my alpha transparency not working correctly in Unity?

Tags: unity, textures, transparency

In Unity I have never seen a bug quite as weird as this one.

As usual, I import my texture with a transparent background and then check the alpha is transparency box and apply it, and everything seemed okay. It had worked like it usually does and made the background of my texture transparent. When I apply it to an object or even just paint it onto the terrain it shows the original texture, but in the areas where there should be nothing it replaces it with some nightmarish plaid hell.

[image]

I have tried other transparent textures but that doesn't seem to work either same result but for each different picture there is a different pattern and color of plaid. I really would appreciate any help I can get on this because I'm just stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I at least figured out a fix for some reason, my toon shader is just acting up and the regular unity shaders are doing just fine, so my first guess is that the toon shader is just not up to date. If I find out anything else I will post it here.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as the accepted answer so that SO's bot doesn't bump it to the top every couple of months.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a different shader on your material. `Unlit/Transparent` should do the trick, though without any lighting.

Comment: I could use a different shader but I'm trying to use a specific one for toon shading. The toon shader was working beautifully about a week ago. I'm not to sure if my unity just updated and has problems with it, because last week I kept postponing the Unity update from quite a while ago.

Comment: Would be useful to see the source of the shader you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem with alpha transparency. I wanted to make object transparent but changing the alpha was not working. Then i set rendering mode to transparent and it worked.